# Where is the Heatmap Plugin

Tags: qgis, plugins, heat-map

I have read the questions about creating heatmaps but I cannot find the Heatmap Plugin in any of the repositories or using the fetch python plugins, it simply is not there. 
Could someone please tell me how to install it.

Comment: There is a good tutorial here: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/07/tutorial-making-heatmaps-using-qgis-and.html

Answer (score 4):

The HEATMAP plugin is available in Plugins -> Manage plug-ins option in Quantum GIS 1.8 version.

You select it and press add. It will then appear as an option in Raster -> Heatmap command line.

Comment: In QGIS version 3.2, the Heatmap plugin appears to have been incorporated into (or replaced by) a menu item in the Processing toolbox (which shows up by default in the righthand side panel), under "[QGIS symbol] Interpolation".

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you have the current standard version Wroclaw 1.74

Please read this post by underdark (in the comments) http://underdark.wordpress.com/2012/03/04/mapping-density-with-hexagonal-grids/ she writes:
"Yes, if you have current QGIS Trunk installed, you can activate a “Heatmap” plugin. It will show up in Raster menu."

Comment: Just to clarify, the easiest way to install the QGIS Trunk, along with standard QGIS, is likely using the [OSGeo4W Installer](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/).  Run the setup program, choose "Advanced Install", then click through until you reach "Select Packages".  Expand the "Desktop Default", and click on both the "qgis" and "qgis-dev" items until the "New" column reflects the same version number as "Current".  Then hit next and this will continue on to install both versions.

Answer (score 1):

While @Kurt came up with the basis of the answer, I think it is worth having the process for obtaining the QGIS Developer Trunk shown explicitly to directly answer @Nick's question of how to install.

This is copied from my comment above:

The easiest way to install the QGIS Trunk, along with standard QGIS, is likely using the [OSGeo4W Installer](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/).

1. Run the setup program, choose "Advanced Install"
2. Click through until you reach "Select Packages".
3. Expand the "Desktop Default"
4. Click on both the "qgis" and "qgis-dev" items until the "New" column
   reflects the same version number as "Current".
5. Hit next and this will continue on to install both versions.